# Python output on windows console getting garbled

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, unicode, cmd

I have a shell script, windows batch script and a python script. Shell script and batch script are entry points for unix and windows based env respectively which in turn invokes python script that takes foreign strings( French, Japanese or Chinese) as input, feeds it into database and displays the same in shell/console terminal. The above works fine in unix env. But while displaying output in windows console the non-english (french or chinese or japanese) strings are getting garbled. Even value in DB is correct in both the cases. But only while displaying in windows console it faults. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to change the pagecode (`chcp` command) and console font to any font that includes the required characters for the required pagecode?

Comment: Default page code in my windows cmd is 850. I changed it to 1252 manually using chcp . It works fine. But is there any way I can achieve this through my python script?

Comment: Start the python script from a batch script after changing pagecode. I don't know enough python to tell if there is a internal way of doing it.